# How to monitor LiveData hasActiveObservers()?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

I have **MyRepository** that obtains a live feed from a server via a socket.

It provides its data to **MyViewModel** via a **MutableLiveData** object which can be observed from a Fragment.

To avoid wasting resources, I don't want **MyRepository** to be obtaining data from the server when there are no observers.

I'd like to know how to monitor **MyRepository**'s **MutableLiveData**, so if there are no observers then **MyRepository** can stop retrieving data from the server. Similarly, if an observer is added, then data retrieval can (re)start.

Currently, I'm just using a basic Thread (see the `createObserversMonitorThread()` method) as the monitor:

```
public class MyRepository {

    private static final String TAG = MyRepository.class.getSimpleName();

    private MutableLiveData<String> mutableLiveData;
    
    private Socket mSocket = null;

    public MyRepository(Application application) {

        mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

        createSocket();
        
        createObserversMonitorThread();
    }

    private void createObserversMonitorThread() {

        Thread thread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    while (isAlive()) {

                        if (mutableLiveData.hasActiveObservers()) {

                            // We have observers, so connect to the server.
                            if (!mSocket.connected()) {
                                mSocket.connect();
                            }
                        }
                        else {

                            // We don't have observers, so disconnect from the server.
                            if (mSocket.connected()) {
                                mSocket.disconnect();
                            }
                        }

                        // Wait until next loop.
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
                }
            }
        };

        thread.setName("MutableLiveData Observers Monitor");
        thread.setPriority(1);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    public LiveData<String> getMutableLiveData() {
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    /**
     * This method posts retrieved data to mutableLiveData.
     */
    private void createSocket() {

        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.SERVER_URL);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected.");
                }
            }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                    if (args[0] instanceof Exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Connect error: ", (Exception)args[0]);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Connect error: " + args[0]);
                    }
                }

            }).on(Socket.EVENT_RECONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Reconnected.");
                }
            }).on(Socket.EVENT_RECONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                    if (args[0] instanceof Exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Reconnect error: ", (Exception)args[0]);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Reconnect error: " + args[0]);
                    }
                }

            }).on(Socket.EVENT_MESSAGE, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                    //Log.d(TAG, "Data received.");

                    String s = (String) args[0];
                    mutableLiveData.postValue(s);
                }

            }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected.");
                }

            }).on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                    if (args[0] instanceof Exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: ", (Exception)args[0]);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + args[0]);
                    }
                }

            });
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create socket", e);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but is there a better way?

**UPDATE**

Solution, thanks to [EpicPandaForce's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62688687/1617737):

```
public class MyRepository {

    private static final String TAG = MyRepository.class.getSimpleName();

    private MutableLiveData<String> mutableLiveData;

    private Socket mSocket = null;

    public MyRepository(Application application) {

        createSocket();

        mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onActive() {
                super.onActive();

                // Connect to server. This will (re)start data being posted on mutableLiveData.
                if (!mSocket.connected()) {
                    mSocket.connect();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onInactive() {
                super.onInactive();

                // Disconnect from server. This will stop data being posted on mutableLiveData.
                if (mSocket.connected()) {
                    mSocket.disconnect();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public LiveData<String> getMutableLiveData() {
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    /**
     * This method posts retrieved data to mutableLiveData.
     */
    private void createSocket() {
        // Same code as before.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `extends LiveData<T>` or `extends MutableLiveData<T>` to get ahold of `onActive()` callback where you are notified if you have at least 1 active observer, and `onInactive()` callback when you went from 1 to 0 active observers.

That way you don't even need to ask for `hasActiveObservers()`.

Comment: Lovely, thank you. I've updated my question with the new code in case it helps anyone else.